# eclipse does not return errorlevel

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, batch-file, p2

I am writing a batch file to install features on eclipse from a local repository.

```
eclipse.exe -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director
  -repository C:/repo,http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/
  -installIU com.app.feature.feature.group
```

but i am not able to detect if the operation failed or succeeded from the batch script. It seems eclipse does not set error level? Any possible workarounds?

Comment: How about checking output of log file?

Comment: BTW, pls file a bug against 'p2' if you think it's a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround that i found is running the command through ant exec instead of calling directly from batch file. It reports all the errors.

```
<exec executable="eclipse.exe" failonerror="true">
  <arg value="-noSplash"/>
  <arg value="-application"/>
  <arg value="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director"/>
  <arg value="-repository"/>
  <arg value="file:C:/repo,http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/"/>
  <arg value="-installIU"/>
  <arg value="com.app.feature.feature.group"/>
</exec>
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=321386) in Equinox 3.6.0 (which was fixed in 3.6.1) that caused failing applications to return an exit code 0. Unless you are using that Equinox version, the p2 director application has a correct exit code.

I suppose the problem lies in how you checked the exit code in the batch script. You can check for non-zero exit codes with `IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO LabelOfErrorHandling`.